# Input character limit check working fine for desktop but not working in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I am checking input character limit.

It's working fine on desktops but not working on mobile devices.

I also tried with on keydown but not happening.

I can use "e.which" but I am not getting "how I can do through it?"

**Yes, it's possible through "onkeyup", but want to know how can I implement same functionality with "onkeyup"?**

Please suggest me changes in my code.

My code snippet:

```
<script>
   $('#bank_ifsc_code').keypress(function(e){
                    var charLength = $(this).val().length+1;
                    if(charLength>11){ return false; }

                    var k = e.keyCode,
                    $return = ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57));
                    if(!$return) { return false; }
   })
</script>
```

Comment: Try the [onInput](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp) Event or the [KeyUp](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) event.

Comment: yes its possible through "onkeyup" but I want to know the logic idea how can i do same functionality through "onkeyup"..

Answer (score 0):

Use the [maxlength](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp) attribute for the length restriction.

```html
<input id="bank_ifsc_code" maxlength="11" />
```

Then, in keyup, you can replace all unwanted characters with a regular expression for example.

```
$("#bank_ifsc_code").keyup(function(e) {
    var val = $(this).val();    
    val = val.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/, "");
    $(this).val(val);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kryptur/xjpwbhfk/4/)

Comment: working fine but "^" is pressed which should not be allowed as per other spl characters

Comment: I fixed the regular expression.

Comment: sorry but.. if i want to allow spl characters also then what will be reg. expression?

Comment: add them to the regex. What characters do you want to add? In your original example, you allowed for letters and numbers.

Comment: now i am trying to change maxlength then its not working?

Comment: It will work with any valid value for maxlength. I don't understand what the problem is?!

Comment: sorry bro.. check your jsfiddle link in mobile.. its also not working on mobile devices..

Comment: Before I posted my answer I checked it on Chrome for Android... What Browser do you use?

Comment: mobile.. chrome..